# MVC3 Razor Camtasia Video Embedding, @ param Error :-(

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, video, syntax, razor, camtasia

Greetings Community!

```
            <object id="myExperienceXXXXXXXX" class="BrightcoveExperience">
              <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
              <param name="width" value="448" />
              <param name="height" value="251" />
              <param name="playerID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
              <param name="playerKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
              <param name="isVid" value="true" />
              <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
              <param name="@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            </object>
```

Notice the last line , I get the following error:

**Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'videoPlayer' does not exist in the current** context

This value is Required by Camtasia to embed my video in my page.  I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I need the "@" sign before the videoPlayer value.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is a reserved character in Razor which should normally be followed by a server side expression. Double it if you want to output it literally:

```
<param name="@@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol is a reserved character in the Razor view engine. If you want to output a `@` symbol you can use two `@` characters to escape the first.

For example:

```
<param name="@@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Not work with the above answers!

It should be the format like this:

```
<param name="@("@videoPlayer")" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```